# D3.JS Multiple Marker or circle on world mao

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I am just trying to use D3.js for a map and have a scenario where I want to create multiple marker in different color for same location.
For an example location New York has 2 category item listed and I category marker in red and another one is in green. How to achieve that.
No matter whatever I do it only rendering one circle.

```
svg.selectAll(".countries").data(countries).enter().append("path").attr("class", "countries").attr("d", path);
    svg.selectAll(".circles")
        .data(listMapData)
        .enter()
        .append("circle")
        .attr("class", "circles")
        .attr("r", function (d) {
            return 13;
        })
        .attr("cx", function (d) {
            let coords = projection([d.Coordinates.Longitude, d.Coordinates.Latitude]);
            return coords[0];
        })
        .attr("cy", function (d) {
            let coords = projection([d.Coordinates.Longitude, d.Coordinates.Latitude]);
            return coords[1];
        })
        .attr("fill", function (d, i) {
            debugger;
            if (d.Category.indexOf("Market Survey") >= 0) return "yellow";
            else if (d.Category.indexOf("Investigation") >= 0) return "red";
            else if (d.Category.indexOf("Lead") >= 0) return "green";
            else if (d.Category.indexOf("Raid") >= 0) return "#943126";
            else if (d.Category.indexOf("Custom Seizure") >= 0) return "#4633FF";
            else if (d.Category.indexOf("Online Investigation") >= 0) return "green";
            else return "#34495E";
        })
```

Comment: Since Long & Lat is same for both category, its look like one dot is hidden behind others dot. Any solution for this?

Comment: Yes, points are perfectly aligned and block one another. There are a few options for this sort of issue, the easiest would be to have a slight random offset to every point, a more complex solution would be detecting overlaps and clustering points around the intended point, using multi colored points where overlaps are detected, etc. If points are exactly the same, then detecting conflicts is a bit easier, if they are similar but slightly different, it'll be a harder task.